# Display Features on OpenLayers Vector only with certain zoom level

Tags: javascript, openlayers

How to display features on Vector Layer depending on zoom level?

For example: I would like to see features on vector layer only if I zoom twice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [documentation](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SettingZoomLevels)

By using [minScale](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.minScale) and [maxScale](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.maxScale).

You can use minResolution and maxResolution as well but it seems that using scales is better.

```
minScale - float -- the minimum scale value at which the layer should display

maxScale - float -- the maximum scale value at which the layer should display

maxResolution - float -- the maximum resolution value at which the layer should display

minResolution - float -- the minimum resolution value at which the layer should display
```